# LSAT question HELP NEEDED

Tags: criminal-law

[image]

[image]

please explain the answer. i chose option c but the answer is option e

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a legal question. LSAT is specifically designed to not contain any actual legal questions, but to test aptitudes in logical reasoning.

Comment: -1 please do not post images of testy. Insteadm use one o th available online  OCR services or re-type the relevant part of the text. See https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1479/should-we-have-an-explicit-policy-against-images-of-text

Comment: This is a **logic** question.

Answer (score 3):

> please explain the answer. i chose option c but the answer is option e

Option C is wrong because it excludes the possibility that most students might have received *exactly* a B minus.

The question permits dividing the group in two subsets. One is {students | grade < B_minus} and the other is its complement {students | grade >= B_minus}.

Option C is in terms of the set {students | grade > B_minus} whereas option E is in terms of the set {students | grade >= B_minus}. Only the latter matches the description.

Answer (score 2):

1. Most (equivalent to "more than half") of the students, attended every session.
2. All students who received a score below B- (that is, C or lower), missed at least one session.
3. Given (1) and (2), more than half of the students received a score of B- or better (better than C).

The difference is "higher than B minus" vs "B minus or higher". A student who received exactly a B minus is included in the latter group, but not the former. "More than half" and "most" are exactly equivalent, at least in this case.

However, this is a logic question, not a law question.